# Change width on GridView EditRowStyle

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple `GridView` with enabled editing on it, but when I click on the `edit` button the width won't wrap around the wrapper. How do I go about changing the width of the edit template?  Here is the basic code below and a picture attached.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="Id" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
         <Columns>
             <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" 
                 ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="ztag" HeaderText="ztag" SortExpression="ztag" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="item" HeaderText="item" SortExpression="item" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="manu" HeaderText="manu" SortExpression="manu" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="model" HeaderText="model" SortExpression="model" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="serial" HeaderText="serial" 
                 SortExpression="serial" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="location" HeaderText="location" 
                 SortExpression="location" />
             <asp:BoundField DataField="division" HeaderText="division" 
                 SortExpression="division" />

         </Columns>
         <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could add the _RowEditing event to the Gridview and, in that code, set the width of the gridview columns.

Add this to your gridview markup.

```
OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing"
```

and this in your code behind.

```
protected void GridView2_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
GridView2.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(20);
//etc>
}
```

If it won't play ball, do it in the PreRender event of the Gridview. You can set a variable to determine whether you are in edit mode, or not, and set the widths of all the columns to suit.

Comment: Hi Martin!

Thanks for the response! This code did not work for me, is there another approach I can take?